# Images load laggy with fade-in animation, tried preloading images but doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi all first post on here

I'm new to programming/web dev, so should be an easy answer hopefully...

I have a simple slideshow....

```
//----SLIDESHOW----

let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
//console.log("slides " + slides);
let slideInstance = 0;

nextSlide();

function nextSlide() {
  console.log("next slide");
  slides[slideInstance].style.display = "none";
  // console.log(slideInstance);
  slideInstance++;
  if (slideInstance > 2) {
    slideInstance = 0;
  }
  slides[slideInstance].style.display = "block";
  console.log(`Slide ${slideInstance} is showing`);
}
function prevSlide() {
  console.log("next slide");
  slides[slideInstance].style.display = "none";
  // console.log(slideInstance);
  slideInstance--;
  if (slideInstance < 0) {
    slideInstance = 2;
  }
  slides[slideInstance].style.display = "block";
  console.log(`Slide ${slideInstance} is showing`);
}
```

All content in the page (including the slideshow) fades in with an animation triggered by the pages scroll position as show below

```
.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.inactive {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```
// ----PAGE SCROLLING----

let inactiveElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".inactive"));
// console.log(inactiveElements);

function isVisible(element) {
  //equation finds if element in view
  const elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  let distanceFromTop = -250;
  let distanceFromBottom = -900;
  if (elementPosition.top - window.innerHeight < distanceFromTop) {
    return true;
  } else return false;
}

function throttle(fn, delay) {
  //throttles rate of 'scanElements' to help performance
  let lastCall = 0;
  return (...args) => {
    let context = this;
    let current = new Date().getTime();
    if (current - lastCall < delay) {
      return;
    }
    lastCall = current;
    return fn.apply(context, ...args);
  };
}

function scanElements() {
  //checks if visible, then assigns css selector
  inactiveElements.forEach((element) => {
    if (isVisible(element)) {
      element.classList.add("active");
    }
    if (!isVisible(element)) {
      element.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", throttle(scanElements, 100));
```

My issue is that the images seem to load laggy and the animation isn't smooth at all, works fine for all sections other than the slideshow.

I tried preloading the images in HTML which didn't work, and also tried using a method I found online although I'm unsure if I executed it well.

```
  <link rel="preload" href="images/toys0.jpg" as="image">
    <link rel="preload" href="images/toys1.jpg" as="image">
    <link rel="preload" href="images/toys2.jpg" as="image">
```

Any ideas? Thanks alot! :)

Comment: `I'm unsure if I executed it well` who knows, we can't tell - but the preload stuff *should* work

Comment: Okay but my point is I've tried this in HTML as you can see and it hasn't worked, is there a difference preloading in JS?

Comment: To answer the preloading in JS question, let me quote the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload#other_resource_preloading_mechanisms) `There are a number of script-based resource loaders out there, but they don't have any power over the browser's fetch prioritization queue, and are subject to much the same performance problems` - now why your code doesn't work?? What browser are you using?

Comment: I suspect the issue is nothing to do with preloading, it's prbably an animation issue

Comment: I'm on Chrome, Issue isn't animation I think as the animation effects the rest of the page content just fine. Also if I retrigger the animation after the initial laggy animation it runs just fine until I refresh, which leads me to think that this is a preloading / loading issue? So do you think I should try a JS preloading method or not? It seems that this is the preferred HTML method in the documentation so is there an alternative and what would you recommend trying first?

Comment: how big are the images? preload won't make them load faster!

Comment: Hmm only about 10mb each, also they don't show instantly on the page so the load speed doesn't necessarily have to be that great. But they SEEM to be loading whenever the .active selector is applied from the scroll js code as shown which is why I'm stumped, the .active selector only affects the opacity so shouldn't it load straight away anyway?

Comment: To clarify: page loads -> scroll down -> .active selector applied to the slideshow which is laggy the first time it appears... This seems to be only happening for the images, but the fade in animation affects the WHOLE page

Comment: You might win some performance in any case by replacing your `scroll` event listener with the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). 10MB is considered very large for an image. If you can, resize and optimze your images.

Comment: Thanks man I didn't realise that was considered large, however I've cut down the size to about 500kb each and it doesn't seem to have affected the performance at all, I'll check out that API to see if that helps.  :)